# Yii Framework: Undefined Variable - keyword

Tags: variables, frameworks, yii, undefined, keyword

```
public function actionSearch()
{   
     $this->showsearch = 1;
     $data['keyword'] = isset($_REQUEST['keyword']) $_REQUEST['keyword']:NULL;
     $data['option'] = isset($_REQUEST['option'])?$_REQUEST['option']:array();
     $data['country'] = isset($_REQUEST['country'])?$_REQUEST['country']:NULL;
     $this->render('search', $data);

}
```

In my View I have,

```
<?php echo CHtml::textField('keyword', $keyword, array('style' => 'width:97%;')); ?>
```

The output says,

```
500
Undefined variable: keyword.
```

Can you tell me what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing '?' after isset($_REQUEST['keyword']). It should be :

```
$data['keyword'] = isset($_REQUEST['keyword'])? $_REQUEST['keyword']:NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if there is some request first

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['keyword']))
```

When you just first load the page there is no request.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have property `keyword` in your model?